# Refresh Google home page using sendkeys ONLY selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

There are many ways of refresh using selenium,I want sendkeys only
I tried online code but not working
can anybody give working code?
I am using windows 10 pro  ,Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) and latest version of selenium

can anybody give code of below and strictly using sendkeys

1) Put some text in google home page
2) refresh

Comment: Why do you want to refresh with sendkeys only after accessing the Google Home Page? What is your exact usecase?

Comment: does it matter?  issue is sendkeys f5 not working

Comment: Where's the code? Which element you've send the sendkeys to? Are you using Actions of Selenium? Please update the code with [mcve]

Comment: driver.get("http://google.com");


Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

element.sendKeys("test data");


WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[4]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]"));

element.sendKeys(Keys.Ctrl.F5);

Comment: anyways code not working,can u give me working one

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: You need to read [ask] carefully. Providing the code you have tried and writing a clear problem statement is *required* and not optional. What's wasting all this time is you don't have those. We're trying to understand why you can't just use `driver.navigate().refresh();` like everyone else. It's built in and works. Using `.sendKeys()` is not going to be reliable and cross-browser. If you would just follow the basic instructions for the site and stop arguing with people that are trying to help you **for free**... you'd probably get an answer a lot faster.

Comment: We don't know why it's not working because you won't post your code. It's likely not working because it just doesn't work anymore. You still haven't explained why the provided method won't work for you.

Comment: u can try with ur code and give,it can be problem with only code or other thing also

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refresh the page with sendkeys. Sendkeys generate the events of keystrokes agasint `WebElement` - not against your browser window. This is why webdriver has a dedicated method to refresh the page.

Comment: many tutorial like https://artoftesting.com/automationTesting/refresh-a-page-in-selenium-webdriver-java.htmlmentions this method, r they wrong?

Comment: I guess so.. Probably they were relevant to elder versions of selenium. I just tried to create a very simple page with no javascript and only a single text input. Sending `Keys.F5` to a text field does not work.

Comment: one thing,sendkeys using normal alphabets is working fine seems issue with function keys

Comment: Yup. I also noticed that.